# How to change android code from compress bitmap to reszie or scaled bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, image-resizing, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

I try to change this code into resized or scaled bitmap cause if I use compress bitmap, it will get too small image. How can I change it?

---

```
FixBitmap3.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream3);
byteArray3 = byteArrayOutputStream3.toByteArray();
ConvertImage3 = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray3, Base64.DEFAULT);
NoLg3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("no_lg");
AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a plugin called Android Drawable Importer that is essential. You can google it and download it. It does the heavy lifting for you with respect to resizing images.